# Empty File when Downloading with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, onedrive

I get an empty file when trying to download either from Google Drive or OneDrive

I guess it must be something pretty straightforward, but I haven't a clue.

Thank you.

```
Private Sub btnDownload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(address as string, destinationFileName As String)
End Sub
```

The file I am trying to download is a text file "file1.txt" with a few lines (5 Kb)

If the address for the Google Drive File is the sharable link, I get a file with the wrong content. On the other hand, when I use the direct link, then I get the empty file.

Comment: OneDrive and Google Drive don't provide you with raw file links you would probably have to use the respective api's and sdk's. This might be a helpful https://codelikeadev.com/blog/google-drive-api-csharp

Comment: https://winaero.com/how-to-unblock-files-downloaded-from-the-internet-in-windows-11/

Comment: [Download & export files - Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#.net)